# Why isn't the password validation working? HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a password validation javascript program in HTML. I've checked, but I don't think there are syntax errors. I don't know what went wrong. The following is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #errorMessage{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Your password should contain at least 6 characters, one number, and one uppercase letter.</p>
    <p>Enter password:</p>
    <br />
    <input id="password" type="password">
    <p>Re-enter password</p>
    <input id="password2" type="password">
    <button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    <p "error"></p>
    
<script>
    function check(){
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
        var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error");
        var errorToThrow = "";
        
        try{
            if(password.length < 6){
                errorToThrow += "<br/> Password too short";
                
            }
            if (/[A-Z]/g.test(password) == false){
                errorToThrow +="<br/> Password should include at least one uppercase letter.";
                
            };
            
            if (/[\d]/g.test(password) == false){
                errorToThrow +="<br/> Password should include at least one digit.";
            };
            
            if(password != password2){
                errorToThrow +="<br/> Passwords do not match";
            }
            throw errorToThrow;
        }
        
        catch(err){
            errorMessage.innerHTML = err;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with it? The browser console says

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at check (passwordvalidation.html:50)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (passwordvalidation.html:19).

It seems like there is an error in the catch part with the errorMessage.innerHTML, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`, which means that `errorMessage` is `null` and so you can't set its `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your html.
should be `<p id="error"></p>`
You didnt have the id specified, so in your js, `document.getElementById("error")` returned null, giving you that error.